# What is the SIGNIFICANCE OF additional byte to char type in JAVA?

Tags: java, types, char, size

what is the logic behind that extra byte?
I know the significance of first byte , but specifically second byte is for what reason?
I want to know the significance of second (eight bits) byte.

Comment: You may need to read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html) article

Comment: or [this one](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: There is well over 64K unicode characters, a byte is not going to be enough. Actually 2 bytes is not enough so Java uses UTF-16 encoding to store code points, i.e. characters above 64K.